# Как обойти защиту сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Установил парсер на windows сервер, всё отлично работает. Но когда идёт работа с сбермегамаркет, то сайт выдаёт ошибку, что используется впн, но его нет. И из-за этого я не могу посещать странницы товаров. Как можно это обойти? Желательно не меняя ip

вот код

```
def parse_sberbank(mass: list):
"""
Функция работы с сбермаркет
:param mass:
:return:
"""

Map_coordinates = dict({
    "latitude": 55.74507757945719,
    "longitude": 37.61949735504636,
    "accuracy": 100
})

result = []

now = datetime.datetime.now()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) "
                     "Chrome/106.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.11.0.2419 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument('--headless')

try:

    for item in mass:
        word_ = -1
        word = item[2].split("\r\n")

        while len(word) - 1 != word_:
            word_ += 1
            with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as browser:
                browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Map_coordinates)
                browser.get(item[3])
```

Comment: Нет никакой информации по тому, что за парсер, как он работает и что хочет извлечь.
Вероятнее всего, в парсер вшито использование прокси, что простым языком, равнозначно впн.
Также могут быть и другие причины, по типу: сайт видит что это явно робот (Парсер не маскирует использование автоматизации) и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте закомментировать строку

```
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) "
                     "Chrome/106.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.11.0.2419 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36")
```

Если не поможет, то попробуйте закомментировать также строку

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Возможно там есть режим который не пропускает безголовый браузер (Но тогда у вас будет открываться браузер визуально и будет выше нагрузка по производительности)

Comment: Это не помогло, я запускаю парсер с сервера, даже если открыть браузер и зайти на сайт, то будет точно такая же ошибка. Точнее всё время перекидывает на сайт с капчей и пишет "Запросы с вашего устройства похожи на автоматические" но даже если вводить капчу, то при открытии товара на сайте, будет ошибка "
Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте отключить VPN или подключиться к другой сети" Но впн не стоит на сервере. Может можно это решить через proxy?

Comment: А сервер у вас где стоит? Вероятнее всего как раз таки это и служит проблемой.
Подключение proxy должно решить проблему.
В общем вам нужно для начала добиться нормального подключения вручную, а затем уже пытаться запустить парсер.

Comment: firstvds, сервер на windows, Москва

Comment: @kaishigo зайдите в браузер на сервере, узнайте свой ip и посмотрите адрес который выдаётся по данному ip